# Find the equation of the plane, in $\bf{r}\cdot n = d$ form

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'll mark the vectors in bold.

$p_1 = \bf{i} - 2 \bf{j} + \bf{k}$

$p_2 = 2 \bf{i} + \bf{j} - \bf{k}$

$p_3 = \bf{i} + \bf{j} + \bf{k}$

Could someone please explain to me the way of finding the equation of a plane in $\bf{r}\cdot n = \bf{d}$ form for a plane containing $p_1, p_2, p_3$?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, what you are looking for is an equation in the form
$$ax + by + cz = d$$
with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, which can be expressed in the form
$$(x,y,z)\cdot\mathbf{n} = d$$
with $\mathbf{n}=(a,b,c)$ the normal vector of the plane.

To find the normal vector of the plane, construct two vectors that *are* in the plane, are not collinear, and take their cross product.

Since you have three points that are not collinear that are in the plane, note that $\mathbf{p1}-\mathbf{p2}$, $\mathbf{p1}-\mathbf{p3}$, and $\mathbf{p2}-\mathbf{p3}$ are all vectors that (after suitable translation) lie in the plane. Once you have the normal vector, finding $d$ is a matter of figuring out what value is required by plugging in at least one point in the plane.

---

**Example.** Suppose you want to find the plane that contains $\mathbf{p}_1=(1,1,1) = \mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{p}_2=(-3,-2,0) = -3\mathbf{i}-2\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{p}_3 = (0,3,1) = 3\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k}$.

The plane contains vectors parallel to
$$\mathbf{p}_1-\mathbf{p}_2 = (1,1,1) - (-3,-2,0) = (4,3,1)$$
and to
$$\mathbf{p}_1 - \mathbf{p}_3= (1,1,1)-(0,3,1) = (1,-2,0).$$
So then the vector $(4,3,1)\times(1,-2,0)$ is perpendicular to plane:
$$(4,3,1)\times(1,-2,0) = \left|\begin{array}{rrr}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k}\\
4 & 3 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 0
\end{array}\right| = \Bigl( 0+2, -(0-1), -8-3\Bigr) = (2,1,-11).$$
Therefore, the plane that contains the three points will have equation of the form
$$2x + y - 11z = d$$
for some $d$. Plugging in $(1,1,1)$, which we know is in the plane, we get
$$d = 2(1) + 1 - 11(1) = -8$$
so the plane in question is the plane with equation
$$2x + y - 11z = -8.$$
Indeed, you can verify that $(1,1,1)$, $(-3,-2,0)$, and $(0,3,1)$ all satisfy the equation. To write in "$\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{n}=\mathbf{d}$ form", we simply write
$$(x,y,z)\cdot(2,1,-11) = -8.$$

Comment: @Arturo In order to find, say, p1 - p2, do I cross-product p1 and p2 or?

Comment: @Sorin: To find $\mathbf{p1}-\mathbf{p2}$, you take $\mathbf{p1}$, and you **subtract** $\mathbf{p2}$. What did you think the `-` stood for?

Comment: @Sorin Cioban:  p1 - p2 can be found by component-by-component subtraction, so is -3i-3j+2k.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I got **n** = 6i + 3k. Thus, d = 6x + 3z.

Comment: @Sorin: No, that cannot be correct. $d$ must be a *constant*, not an expression involving $x$s, $y$s, or $z$s. It has to be a **number.**

Comment: Now it's clearer. I didn't know I had to plug in one of the p's components in order to find d. Thanks. So in my case, I got **n** = 6i + 3k; after plugging, say, p3 (1,1,1), I'd get d = 9.

Comment: @Sorin: Well, to double check, just plug in the three points and verify that they all satisfy the equation. If they do, you're right.

Comment: Yep, they all give the same result. Thanks a lot!